# Multiple threads writing to same list in java and return that list to a function

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

So I have a really large list of zip codes (about 80,000) that I want to pass onto a url and get the JSON data from that url for each zip code.
I am running a query on that JSON to see if it has the end_lat and if it does then I want to save that zip code to a list.
As I am fetching and matching JSON for a lot of zip codes its taking forever.

So I tried few different methods to make it a multi threaded application. I tried the good old Thread method with runnable interface.
I tried executor services. But everything stops abruptly which makes me believe that I should be making synchronized writes to that list.

```
public void breakingZipCodesForThreads() {
  List<String> zip_Codes = Serenity.sessionVariableCalled("zipCodes");
  int size = (int) Math.ceil(zip_Codes.size() / 5.0);
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
  for (int start = 0; start <  zip_Codes.size(); start += size) {
    int end = Math.min(start + size,  zip_Codes.size());
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(zip_Codes.subList(start, end));
    executor.execute(worker);
    }




//run() method bascially has this code for a function
for (String zipCode :  zip_Codes) {
     currentPage  = pageUrl + zipCode;
     Response response = given().urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                             .when()
                             .get(currentPage);
        try {
            Object end_lat = response.getBody().path("end_lat");
            if (end_lat != null && !end_lat.toString().isEmpty()) {
                   resultantZipCode.add(zipCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
               //Something else
            }
```

So essentially I want all my threads to concurrently write to the list "resultantZipCode" and in the end give me single list for all the zipcodes in there that satisfy my condition. 
So how do I make my zip codes break into pieces, run parallely for the run function and save all the resultant zip codes and returns me that list? What am I missing?

Comment: Java already provides datastructures for multi-threaded read/write.

Comment: You need to use threadsafe implementation of `List` or `Set` to store zip codes (`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for example )

Comment: @Ivan A `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is neither a `List` nor a `Set`. I think what you meant to suggest is wrapping the `List` in `Collections#synchronizedList`.

Comment: @JacobG. Yes, but if OP only needs to use collection to store data and iterate `Queue` interface in OK. And `Collections.synchronizedXXX()` are not very performant as each method blocks whole collection. `ConcurrentSkipListSet` will also work but in that case elements in that set will also be sorted

Comment: What exactly does "everything stops abruptly" mean? Does your program terminate with an exception? Does it hang?